# .then-callback returns 'undefined', but logging shows the correct output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make an API-call to get a json-object to populate a dropdown menu. When the method .getAllCurrencies() is called it returns 'undefined'. If I replace the return statement of the jsonRes with a simple console.log(jsonRes) it shows the correct data.

```
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
const baseURI = 'http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=';

const CurrencyLayer = {
  getAllCurrencies() {
    fetch(`${baseURI}${apiKey}`, )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonRes => {
      return jsonRes
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  },
}

export default CurrencyLayer;
```

I do not get any error messages. Why is this happening (to me)? ;)

Comment: What do you think `.then(jsonRes => {return jsonRes})` is doing?  Do you think that is returning the value to whatever called `getAllCurrencies`?  It's not, you need to return the `fetch` and call `then` in whatever scope called `getAllCurrencies`.

Comment: Your issue looks link a misunderstanding of the asynchronous behavior of javascript. There are many ways to fix it, but you should really read about it. I just found [this blog entry](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) and you may look for _asynchronous javascript_ in google for more. This about your whole architecture, and we cannot give you the best solution with only this bunch of code.

Comment: `getAllCurrencies` returns nothing so it will be undefined

Comment: There are a couple issues, but the main issue is that you aren't returning anything from `getAllCurrencies()`.  Try `return fetch(...` You don't need the second `then()`. You'll then need to use `getAllCurrencies().then(val => // use val)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const CurrencyLayer = {
  getAllCurrencies() {
    return fetch(`${baseURI}${apiKey}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  },
}
```

There.
The mistakes were:

1. You did not return the promise generated by `fetch` from the function.
2. No need for a special block to return `res.json()`. This anonymous function already returns the result implicitly: `res => res.json()`, which is equivalent to:

```
res => {
    return res.json();
}
```